# Spring Boot application giving JDBC connection not found error quite often

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, dbconnection

My Spring boot application is using Spring Data JPA to interact with a AWS MySQL RDS. The application is deployed on 2 ec2 instances on top of ELB.
MySQL DB has a maximum connection limit of 147 connections, so I have added following entry in my application-prod.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000 
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=70
```

After this my application runs fine for few days but then I again start getting JDBC connection not found error.

On further debugging running following command on my MySQl gives me only 73 active connections whereas for the time when application was running properly, it returned 143.

Could it be possible that 1 of the ec2 instance is stopped or terminated?
If so what can I do to debug further?

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
```

I have had a hard time to debug this issue, need some help.

Comment: 70 connections is almost certainly too many; 15-20 is more usual.

Comment: @chrylis: yes, i agree. And 1 instance will always have apool of 70 connections, still getting no JDBC connections. Not sure why?

Comment: How did you solved this issue